# Returning a double pointer to an object of template class

Tags: c++, pointers, typename

I have a template class:

```
template<class T> 
class CVariable
{
     //lines ommited
};
```

and another class:

```
class CLengthUnits:public CUnits
{
     //lines ommited
};
```

but when i try to return from a function:

```
CVariable<CLengthUnits>** PointsOfSection(void)
{
     //lines ommited
}
```

the compiler gives me an error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Remove the 2 stars after CVariable in your first fragment

Comment: Is this actual code? `class CVariable** {}` is a syntax error.

Comment: Best to pick up a good book about C++ and learn about classes and templates first before moving on to pointers!

Comment: Have you included the header file that defines `CVariable`?

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T> 
class CVariable**
{
   //lines ommited
};
```

The asterisks don't belong there. Remove them.

---

**EDIT**: In response to OP's comment, the following program compiles just fine for me:

```
class CUnits {};

template<class T>
class CVariable
{
     //lines ommited
};

class CLengthUnits:public CUnits
{
     //lines ommited
};

CVariable<CLengthUnits>** PointsOfSection(void)
{
     //lines ommited
}
```

I think there is something you are still not telling us.

Comment: sorry, wrong typing. Of course, these asterisks don't belong here. The problem is in:CVariable<CLengthUnits>** PointsOfSection(void)
{
     //lines ommited
}

Comment: @user1022110: Fix the question then and post the real error, problem description and mark the line.

Comment: @panos Lesson to learn: don't type your code in SO. Reduce your program to the smallest possible complete program that demonstrates the error. Then copy-paste (**not** retype) your program into your question.

Comment: thank you Rob. This project is a dll, so maybe something else is going on with my code. I just thought that it was the double pointer who caused the problem.

Comment: You are welcome, @panos. Given the error message, consider whether the definition of `CVariable` is not visible at the location it is used. Do you forget an `#include`? Or maybe it is in a different namespace?

Comment: God! you are absolutely right! beside a long .h file, I missed some extra {}, who kicked the function out of the namespace, where it should be. Thanks again a lot.